# Union table from several schemas with variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 12 schemas: A1, B1, C1, A2, B2 , C2 , A3, B3, D3 etc.

I need help in writing a query that will UNION the same table from all schemas using loop.

i.e:

```
DECLARE vIndex Number;
BEGIN
   FOR vIndex IN 1..12 LOOP
       SELECT *
       FROM 'A' || &vIndex || '.Table'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM 'B' || &vIndex || '.Table'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM 'C' || &vIndex || '.Table'
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Is the number of schemas variable? In case not, why don't you just try with a plain query?

Comment: The number of schemas is not a variable, the variable is in the schema name

Comment: But the tables is always the same? Do you know the name of this table or is it variable itself?

Comment: I have the table name. so what do you mean by plain query?

Comment: a query without loops

Comment: I can't since each year there is going to be additional number.
12 = 2019
11 = 2018 etc.
Next year we are going to have 13 so I need it to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You will need dynamic sql for it. Also there is no need of declaring `vIndex`

Something like following will help:

```
DECLARE 
  V_sql varchar2(4000);
  --TYPE V_ALL_REC_TYPE IS TABLE OF A1.TABLE%ROWTYPE; -- one of the table name from any schema 
  --V_ALL_REC V_ALL_REC_TYPE;
  Cur1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
   FOR vIndex IN 1..3 LOOP -- use range according to your need
     V_sql:= v_sql 
       || case when vIndex > 1 then ' UNION ALL ' END ||
       'SELECT *
       FROM A' || vIndex || '.Table
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM B' || vIndex || '.Table
       UNION ALL
       SELECT *
       FROM C' || vIndex || '.Table ';
   END LOOP;

   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE ' || V_sql; -- DIRECTLY INSERT DATA TO YOUR TABLE AS MENTIONED IN THE COMMENT.
 Open cur1 for v_sql;
 DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur1); -- use this
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm getting the following error:
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 19, column 33:
PLS-00597: expression 'V_ALL_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 19, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Ok, you need to use the proper type to store the result. I have just made your task of UNIONS. all other things are ideal code

Comment: What should be the type? I need to store results to a table

Comment: Then, in that case, you don't need to add your result to the variable, You can directly insert the result of the query into the table using: `INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE <YOUR UNION QUERY>` -- See my updated answer now!!

Comment: Thanks but it will not work for me since I do not have WRITE permissions in this DB

Comment: You need to store the result to the table and you dont have permission? How will you do that now? You are very unclear.

Comment: I apologize if it was not clear from the beginning. I want just to query the DB with loop and use a variable to make it dynamic